# How to parse Json payload in Cloud Function triggered from Pub/sub

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to google cloud function and Node Js and keep getting this error, when i am trying to parse Json payload

```
exports.processdata = (event, context) => {

  const pubsubMessage = event;

 var obj = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString());
console.log(obj.temp);


};
```

error

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
Function.Buffer.from
```

CLoud function is running on Node.Js version 8

Comment: As seen in the error you have received your first argument which I suppose is the one you have attached in the code sample 'event' should be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array or array-like which basically tells you, you need to define it as one of these.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the json payload by using the property **.json** and below is the complete code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.processdata = functions.pubsub.topic('topic-np').onPublish((message) => {
  // [START readJson]
  // Get the `name` attribute of the PubSub message JSON body.
  let name = null;
  try {
    name = message.json.name;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('PubSub message was not JSON', e);
  }
```

Reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events

And if you are testing the cloud function which triggers on Pub/Sub, publish the message in topic and then verify via logs in your cloud function.